# Sending text message through email address - Messages out of order

Tags: php, wordpress, email, mail-server

I have an app running in wordpress ( using $wpdb ) to send a text through email. They send to a 1234567890@vtext.com address, which texts their mobile phone.

I've noticed that some carriers treat long texts as a media message, so my code splits long messages into multiple emails. Here's that code:

```
for ( $i=0; $i<count($recipientEmail); $i++ ) {
        $to = $recipientEmail[$i];
        if ( strlen($message) > 115 ) {
            // ceil rounds any fractions up
            $numTexts = ceil(strlen($message) / 115);
            $zero = 0;
            $onetwentyfive = 115;
            $noRepeatconfirmations = '';
            for ( $n=0; $n<$numTexts; $n++ ) {
                $messagePart = substr($message, $zero, $onetwentyfive);
                $messagePart .= "\r\n".($n+1)." of ".$numTexts;
                if ($n > 0 ) {
                    $messagePart = '-'.$messagePart;
                }
                // if ( !filter_var( $to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
                if ( !wp_mail($to, $subject, $messagePart, $headers) ) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if ( $noRepeatconfirmations !== $recipientEmail[$i] ) {
                        $total .= $recipientEmail[$i].", ";
                    }
                    $noRepeatconfirmations = $recipientEmail[$i];
                }
                $zero += 115;
                $onetwentyfive += 115;
            }
        } else {
            // if ( !filter_var( $to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
            if ( !wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $total .= $recipientEmail[$i].", ";
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when I send a long alert to myself it sends in the correct order, but when I'm sending a message to 150+ people it sends in a weird order (3rd, 1st, 2nd).

I was wondering if there's a method I could use in my code or a setting on my mail sever i can use to make the messages send in order.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26661243/ it may help you to understand how to sort an array. I did not downvote btw. I know sorting arrays can be difficult at times and I won't be able to help any further Nicholas. If that answer doesn't help or seems to complicated, further your research on Google using "sort numbers array PHP". Good luck.

Comment: By the way, sending SMS via email works in small volumes, but don't expect the carriers to allow it if you start pushing high volume. For that you'll need something like Twilio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee SMS, MMS, or email messages will be received in the order they were sent, short of spacing them out 10 seconds or so apart.  **Hopefully** message A will be delivered before B is sent, and B is delivered before C, and so on.

Even still this is not 100% as some mail servers will queue up messages before delivery (sender and receiving end points).

It's just the nature of the beast.

NOTE: I'm not 100% sure on MMS, but 100% positive on email, and about 75% on SMS.

Comment: Might want to look into using an SMS gateway API.  The biggest hurdle I see is using email for the delivery.  Take a look at something like http://www.message-media.com/business/products/integration#developer-apis

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I'll just limit the message to a certain length. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I just had the idea to instead of sending 3 emails at a time per user, send each user the first part, then send the second part, ect. I'm thinking this should solve the issue, since sending to 150 users will be enough of a delay.

Comment: Might Work,... But I Said,... Still not a guarantee,... Especially if the servers queue messages for delivery (It's an outdated [IMO] tactic used to minimize bandwidth and load, but it's still done).