# PHP array out sort in desc order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

my code here: i try to use sort function but not success. this is my working array code :

MY code desplay output not sorted order:

```
<?php

 foreach($aCities as $key=>$val)
 {
     foreach($diskspace[$val] as $key=>$val2)
     {
         if(isset($val2['data']))
         {
             //'MBytes %.f'=155.000000%;
             preg_match("/'(.*?)ytes \%.f'=(.*?)\%;/",$val2['data'],$aVal);
             echo($val.' '.ceil($aVal[2]).' '.$aVal[1].'<br />');
         }
     }
 }
?>
```

Code OUTPUT:

```
S 3 MB
T 6 MB
I 10 MB
```

i need output in DESC(MemorySize) order like :

```
I 10 MB
T 6  MB
S 3  MB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $out = array();

 foreach($diskspace as $key => $value) // parse original array
 {
     $row = array_values($value);
     $row = $row[0];
     preg_match('/=(\d+)\./', $row['data'], $match); // get numerical value
     // MB as you did not show what else can be    
     $out[] = array($key, $match[1] + 0, 'MB'); // convert $match[1] to integer 
 }

 uasort($out, function ($a, $b) {  // sort by the second column
    return $a[1] < $b[1] ? 1 : -1; 
 });

 foreach($out as $row) // output sorted data
    echo join(' ', $row) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using [rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)?

**EDIT**

For example, if you have an array of numbers `$number_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and you use the function rsort(): `rsort($number_array)` the resulting array will have the values `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` in that order.

For your example however, judging by your code, it looks like you might be better off using [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

You can use it as a closure as well.

`usort($diskspace, function($a, $b) { return $b[0]['data'] - $a[0]['data']; }`

I would attempt something like the above. Without testing it myself it should return an array of arrays like you have ordered by your data highest to lowest. The `[0]` would effectively be comparing the data property of the first element of each of the arrays which shouldn't be a problem since each of your arrays composing `$aCities` has only one element.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression you were already using the sort() function. I will update my answer.

Comment: rsort() sorts from highest to lowest in the case of integer values. Answer updated to utilize usort() which would be sorting by a user-defined function.

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($diskspace, function($a, $b) {
    $a = reset($a); $b = reset($b);
    $aVal = filter_var($a['data'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $bVal = filter_var($b['data'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if ($aVal == $bVal) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ($aVal > $bVal) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
});

var_dump($diskspace);
```